# Single expression to get combined parent+child attributes?

Tags: xpath

Suppose I have a document like this:

```
<sentence group="A">
  <word type="1"/>
  <word type="2"/>
</sentence>
<sentence group="B">
  <word type="1"/>
</sentence>
```

...and I want output like this:

```
"A-1"
"A-2"
"B-1"
```

Is there a single xpath expression that would return this? Note the exact form of output is not essential, the main thing is the combination of parent-child attributes.

EDIT: My question really should have included desired xpath version, which in my case unfortunately is 1.0. So I accepted @Michael Kay's answer that clarified that it cannot be done in version 1.0.

Note @Fravadona's suggestion might work for xpath 2.0.

Comment: Please, with XPath questions, specify a version of XPath. That's because there are lots of people still using XPath 1.0 despite the fact that it has been superseded 15 years ago; and if an XPath problem is tricky enough to be worth raising on SO, then the solution for later XPath versions will usually be much simpler than the 1.0 solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this can be done in XPath 1.0, for the following reasons:

- XPath 1.0 does not have a data type for a set or sequence of strings
- You can't return the result as a nodeset because the values you want in the result are not the values of nodes that exist in the input
- XPath 1.0 does not have a function like string-join to form a single string from a set of input strings.

@Fravadona has supplied an answer that will work in XPath 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use XPath 2.0 then the following expression should do what you want:

```
//word/concat(parent::sentence/@group,"-",@type)
```

for each `word` node, concatenate:

- the `group` attribute of its `sentence` parent-node
- a dash
- its `type` attribute.

Comment: Would you mind breaking this down for me please? Also, note I have changed node names in my example, because I thought the original ones might collide with xpath terms ("parent").

Comment: No, XPath 1.0 does not allow a function call on the RHS of "/". This is OK in XPath 2.0, but not 1.0.

Comment: There is no need to change your element names. XPath is carefully designed to allow element names to clash with keywords such as "parent", "div", "true" etc

Comment: Thank @MichaelKay - it is good to know xpath is robust like that. On the other hand, it is much easier for the reader (especially if its me) to understand a piece of code if there are no clashes like that :)